# Why does insertion sort stops working in this case?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

In the function ***insertionSort***, I have defined a variable ***temp*** which is equivalent to ***arr[i]***. For the following ***while loop*** I have written some conditions one of them is ***temp < arr[j])***, this code works perfectly fine. BUT if I replace this ***temp*** with ***arr[i]*** in the condition **[** i.e *while(j >= 0 && arr[i] < arr[j])* **]** this code does work as intended. Why is this happening aren't the values of the variable ***temp*** and ***arr[i]*** the same, as is defined 2 lines above it ? 
 
With ***while(j >= 0 && arr[i] < arr[j])***, it does not work.
[image: wrong]
With ***while(j >= 0 && temp < arr[j])***, it works.
[image: right]

```
#include<iostream>

void printSortedArray(int arr[], int size){
    std::cout<<"{ ";
    for(int m=0; m<size-1; ++m){
    std::cout<<arr[m]<<", ";
    }
    std::cout<<arr[size-1]<<" ";
    std::cout<<"}";
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int size){
for(int i=1; i<size; ++i){
    int temp = arr[i];                     //  <---- Variable *temp* ----
    int j = i - 1;
    while(j >= 0 && temp < arr[j]){        //  <---- *while loop*----
        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
        --j;
    }
    arr[j+1] = temp;
}

printSortedArray(arr, size);
}

int main(){
int n; std::cout<<"Enter the size of array : ";
std::cin>>n;

int arr[n];

for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    std::cout<<"Enter the element at index ~ "<<i<<" : ";
    std::cin>>arr[i];
}

insertionSort(arr, n);
}
```

Comment: 1) Why images instead of copy-pasted text? 2) Did you step through, your code, with the debugger, to see what is the difference between those 2 cases?

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition should be `while (j > 0 && temp < arr[j])`
and
the end   `arr[j] = temp;` instead of `arr[j+1] = temp;`